# Keep Dotnet Core Grpc Server running as a console application?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, grpc

I am trying to keep a Grpc server running as a console daemon. This gRPC server is a microservice that runs in a docker container.

All of the examples I can find make use of the following:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This does indeed block the main thread and keeps it running but does not work in docker with the following error:

```
"Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read."
```

Now I could probably try to find a workaround for docker specifically, but this still doesn't feel right. Does anyone know of a good "production ready" way to keep the service running?

Comment: It'll work if you use `-it` when starting up the docker container. If that doesn't work for you, you can just sleep the main thread indefinitely with `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`

Comment: Docker container is deployed into a kubernetes cluster on a cloud platform. Interactive containers are not an option. Problem with Thread.Sleep is that there is no graceful shutdown of grpc server when the container is stopped for example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can now use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` pacakge which is a hosting and startup infrastructures for both asp.net core and console application.

Like asp.net core, you can use the HostBuilder API to start building gRPC host and setting it up. The following code is to get a console application that keeps running until it is stopped (for example using Control-C):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();

         // register your configuration and services.
        ....

        await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
    }
}
```

In order to run the gRPC service, you need to start/stop `Grpc.Core.Server` in a hosted service. A hosted service is basically a piece of code that is run by the host when the host itself is started and the same for when it is stopped. This is represented in the IHostedService interface. That's to say, implement a GrpcHostedService to override the interface:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Grpc.Host
{
    public class GrpcHostedService: IHostedService
    {
        private Server _server;

        public GrpcHostedService(Server server)
        {
            _server = server;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _server.Start();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await _server.ShutdownAsync();
    }
}
```

It's simple really. We get an `GrpcHostedService` instance injected through dependency injection and run StartAsync on it when host is started. When the host is stopped we run StopAsync so that we can gracefully shut everything down including Grpc server.

Then go back to the `Program.cs` and make some changes:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
             // Add configuration, logging, ...
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // Better to use Dependency Injection for GreeterImpl
                Server server = new Server
                {
                    Services = {Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl())},
                    Ports = {new ServerPort("localhost", 5000, ServerCredentials.Insecure)}
                };
                services.AddSingleton<Server>(server);
                services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, GrpcHostedService>();
            });

        await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
    }
}
```

By doing this, the generic host will automatically run StartAsync on our hosted service, which in turn will call StartAsync on the `Server` instance, essentially start the gRPC server.

When we shut down the host with Control-C, the generic host will automatically call StopAsync on our hosted service, which again will call StopAsync on the `Server` instance which will do some clean up.

For other configuration in HostBuilder, you can see this [blog](http://www.minepla.net/2018/03/net-core-2-1-ihost-ihostbuilder-hostbuilder-webhost-iwebhostbuilder/).

Comment: Hey, this available in .net core 2.0 or only 2.1=< ?

Comment: This is available in .net core 2.0 while the package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting version is 2.1.0-preview1-final and LangVersion is 7.1 in order to use async main

Comment: So now we can run this service in console-mode, that means when I accedentaly close the console, my service is gone. Is there a way to run this as/inside a windows-service with usage of the microsoft components instead of using e.g. dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service?

Comment: I run the console app in docker (mostly Linux docker). The benifit from using `HostBuilder` is the service can be hosted without additional code (`Console.ReadKey` or `ManualResetEvent`) and it supports gracefully shutdown. Not sure about running it inside a windows-service. But since asp.net core can do that way with some extensions code, so console app also can be hosted in a windows service. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Seems the ASP.NET team has implemented it: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/samples/GenericHostSample/ServiceBaseControlled.cs  Guess it would be published in 2.1

Comment: .net core 2.1 completely solves this problem. Going to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ManualResetEvent` to block the main thread until you receive a shutdown event.

For example in a trivial situation:

```
class Program
{
  public static ManualResetEvent Shutdown = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Waiting in other thread...");
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      Shutdown.Set();
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for signal");
    Shutdown.WaitOne();

    Console.WriteLine("Resolved");
  }
}
```

For example, in your case, I imagine something like:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Core;
using Helloworld;

namespace GreeterServer
{
  class GreeterImpl : Greeter.GreeterBase
  {
    // Server side handler of the SayHello RPC
    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
      Program.Shutdown.Set(); // <--- Signals the main thread to continue 
      return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply {Message = "Hello " + request.Name});
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    const int Port = 50051;

    public static ManualResetEvent Shutdown = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Server server = new Server
      {
        Services = {Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl())},
        Ports = {new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure)}
      };
      server.Start();

      Shutdown.WaitOne(); // <--- Waits for ever or signal received

      server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One also can use the `async Main` and use the `TaskCompletionSource` object instead, this will free the main thread for some other work to do.

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of setting up a separate event when you can just do `server.ShutdownTask.Wait();`? That will wait until the server itself shuts down (Shutting down the service is a separate matter, but should be handle automagically via the `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading`  event or you can override and shutdown the service yourself.