# .net core run IHostedService in windows-service

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, console-application

So, using the new HostBuilder in .net core 2.1.0-preview1-final, we can run a console app in console-service-mode, but that means when I accidentaly close the console, my service will be stopped.

Is there a way to run this console-service-app as/inside a windows-service with usage of some microsoft .net core components instead of using e.g. dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service? or other 3rd parties?

I created a (non Grpc) service like in this question:
[Keep Dotnet Core Grpc Server running as a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989148/keep-dotnet-core-grpc-server-running-as-a-console-application)

I'm aware of the 3rd party tools over here:
[Writing windows service in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763942/writing-windows-service-in-net-core)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848141/netcore-2-1-generic-host-as-a-servicehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848141/netcore-2-1-generic-host-as-a-service