# NetCore 2.1 Generic Host as a service

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to build a Windows Service using the latest Dotnet Core 2.1 runtime. I'm NOT hosting any aspnet, I do not want or need it to respond to http requests.

I've followed the code found here in the samples:  https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/generic-host/samples/2.x/GenericHostSample

I've also read this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1

The code works great when run inside of a console window using dotnet run.  I need it to run as a windows service.  I know there's the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices, but that's for the WebHost, not the generic host.  We'd use host.RunAsService() to run as a service, but I don't see that existing anywhere.

How do I configure this to run as a service?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {


        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var host = new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
                    {
                        configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                        configHost.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
                        configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
                        configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
                    })
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                    {
                        configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                        configApp.AddJsonFile(
                            $"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
                            optional: true);
                        configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
                        configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddLogging();
                        services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
                    })
                    .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
                    {
                        configLogging.AddConsole();
                        configLogging.AddDebug();

                    })

                    .Build();

                await host.RunAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {



            }
        }


    }

    #region snippet1
    internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private Timer _timer;

        public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is working.");
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

EDIT:  I repeat, this is not to host an ASP.NET Core app.  This is a generic hostbuilder, not a WebHostBuilder.

Comment: Not a dupe.  That is for hosting asp.net core.  WebHost.RunAsService.  I'm not using a WebHost, I'm using a generic host.

Comment: Again, look at the host builder.  It's not a WebHostBuilder for listening for http requests.  It's a generic HostBuilder, designed for running background tasks ONLY, and it doesn't listen for http requests.  Required reading:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: did you find a proper solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have said you simply need to reuse the code that is there for the `IWebHost` interface here is an example.

```
public class GenericServiceHost : ServiceBase
{
    private IHost _host;
    private bool _stopRequestedByWindows;

    public GenericServiceHost(IHost host)
    {
        _host = host ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(host));
    }

    protected sealed override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        OnStarting(args);

        _host
            .Services
            .GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>()
            .ApplicationStopped
            .Register(() =>
            {
                if (!_stopRequestedByWindows)
                {
                    Stop();
                }
            });

        _host.Start();

        OnStarted();
    }

    protected sealed override void OnStop()
    {
        _stopRequestedByWindows = true;
        OnStopping();
        try
        {
            _host.StopAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        finally
        {
            _host.Dispose();
            OnStopped();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnStarting(string[] args) { }

    protected virtual void OnStarted() { }

    protected virtual void OnStopping() { }

    protected virtual void OnStopped() { }
}

public static class GenericHostWindowsServiceExtensions
{
    public static void RunAsService(this IHost host)
    {
        var hostService = new GenericServiceHost(host);
        ServiceBase.Run(hostService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you found the solution for this problem.

In my case I used generic host (introduced in 2.1) for such purpose and then just wrap it up with systemd to run it as a service on Linux host.

I wrote a small article about it https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/june/clean-service-stop-on-linux-with-net-core-21/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`IHostedService` if for [asp.net core] backendjob,
if u want to build a  windows service on .net core, u should reference this package [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/), and use `ServiceBase` as base class.
(you can also start from a .net framework windows service and then change the `.csproj` file)

---

edit: please see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and  this code https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices/WebHostWindowsServiceExtensions.cs.
To create a windows service `ServiceBase` for manage your `IHost`

Comment: you too have the problem understanding the difference between IWebHost and IHost.  The link you provided is for IWebHost.  This project is for IHost, it does not listen for http requests.  I'm not going to use IWebHost because it makes no sense for the service to listen for http requests.  Required reading:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: yes, the link is for `IWebHost` , but it's almost the same as `IHost`, what I try to tell u is how to run it under windows service eg `ServiceBase`,  It's not difficult to understand, What the `RunAsService` extensions method do is that it create a simple ServiceBase class named `WebHostService` to start/stop the IWebHost (IHost in your case)